# Globbing with symfony doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, date, doctrine

I want to retrieve data from a certain date to an another.
The thing is, my date in Database is formated this way: YYYY-mm-dd hh:mm.
The date I am using is only YYYY-mm-dd.

I tried this:

```
$leds = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('l')
    ->from('AppBundle:Lead', 'l')
    ->where('l.created_at BETWEEN ":endDate*" AND ":startDate*"')
    ->setParameter('endDate', $endDate)
    ->setParameter('startDate', $startDate)
    ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

The final SQL request is

```
SELECT * FROM bar_contacts WHERE created_at BETWEEN "2015-11-30*" AND "2017-09-20*";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$leds = $em->createQueryBuilder()
->select('l')
->from('AppBundle:Lead', 'l')
->where('l.created_at BETWEEN ":endDate*" AND ":startDate*"')
->setParameter('endDate', $endDate." 23:59")
->setParameter('startDate', $startDate." 00:00")
->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: I did quite the same, but in fact on line `->where('l.created_at BETWEEN ":endDate*" AND ":startDate*"')` , the stars are the error. There's is no globbing.

Comment: The idea is to not use stars.  And if created_at is an actual datetime field then just use DATE(l.created_at) and let the database take care of it.  You will need to add a doctrine extension to handle DATE.